# Why is this JSON value undefined?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable `json`, which when I call `console.log(json)` it outputs `{"buildingName":"", "addressLine1":"", "postcode":""}`

Why, when I call `console.log(json.postcode)` do I get `undefined`?

**EDIT**

`console.log(typeof json)` does indeed output 'string'. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Please create a working snippet.

Comment: Probably because `typeof json === 'string'`. That'd be my first guess.

Comment: please share the output of `console.log(typeof json);`

Comment: Why do I get a load of downvotes for a question that turns out to have a perfectly acceptable answer? How could I have asked this question better?

Comment: All the answers are absolutely spot on and this has helped me, so I don't see why it's such a bad question!

Comment: Hmm it's a shame because I did honestly try to debug this but just hadn't enough javascript experience to figure it out myself (e.g. knowing to use typeof, or even realising that the way it was printing to the console was as a string and not as an object.). I think others could benefit from this. It may be a simple solution but not obvious when you don't know. I had been trying things for over 30 minutes wondering why it wasn't working. Now I learnt something about JSON parsing/stringified JSON.

Comment: @Durga thanks for the feedback nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `json` must be a string that is why you get `undefined` when accessing the property `postcode`

**ERROR CODE**

```js
var json = '{"buildingName":"", "addressLine1":"", "postcode":""}';
console.log(json.postcode);
```

So, what you need to do is parse the `json` variable to get the parsed json and then access the `postcode`. Since, the `postcode` is empty you do not get anything printed in the console for this property:

**WORKING CODE**

```js
var json = '{"buildingName":"", "addressLine1":"", "postcode":""}';
var json = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(json.postcode);
```

Answer (score 5):

`json` is still a string and you need to `JSON.parse` it to turn it into an object. Right now you're trying to access the undefined property `postcode` of `String`.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a **JSON**, it's a string, so it doesn't have that property. You are trying to use it as an object (the **O** in **JSON**).

You can turn it into an object by doing

```
let object = JSON.parse(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the JSON string into an object. For this, try `$.parseJSON(json)`.

A working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var json = '{"buildingName":"", "addressLine1":"", "postcode":"xyz"}';
  var parsedStr = $.parseJSON(json);
  console.log(parsedStr.postcode);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your real syntax is:

```
json = '{"buildingName":"", "addressLine1":"", "postcode":""}';
```

That's a string. In order to change it into an object you need to parse it into an object like this:

```
data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Now you can log the object and it's content. Rather than just the string:

```
console.log(data);
console.log(data.postcode);
```